# How to implement User Interface for Microservice Application based on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices

There are numerous articles such as [this one](https://microservices.io/patterns/ui/client-side-ui-composition.html), which insist that while implementing microservices, each team should build its own UI. These fragments can be composed into a single page using iFrames or div.
My question is, how to implement using AWS. 
This could be done at deployment time, or runtime.
 1. Deployment time: HTML fragments need to be collected as part of CI/CD process and put together in S3 which serves as web server for static pages (API GW for dynamic JSON content).
 2. Run time: The html fragment (div)will have to be delivered to client browser on demand, as and when client clicks through (can be cached in client browser, and/or API GW.
What is the technology for this? I don't think Lambdas can deliver HTML fragments through API GW. Also, the CI/CD approach appears to be fuzzy to me.
Btw any other way? Thanks

Comment: What tech stack/technology do you use for your Frontend?

Comment: We are using AWS. It could be any cloud architecture. UI is ReactJS. Static web infrastructure is hosted on S3 as a monolith.

Answer (score 1):

Use SPA like angular/react (but not limited to. Same method can be implemented in MPA).
SPA helps us to segregate the UI from the back-end and both runs independently. 
And in the service layer of the application(UI), call the respective micro-service say M1 or M2.
In monolithic applications like MPA (multi page application- spring/struts/jsp) where the UI is generated from the back-end and are tightly coupled you need to call different rest-api using jquery/ajax and process the JSON response.

In SPA multiple scenarios like parallel trigger all micro-services or wait for M1 and pass the payload to M2 or race between M1 and M2 can be achieved using promises in javascript